# Regarding the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The complex plane consists of the complex axis(represented by the y-axis) and the real axis(represented by the x-axis). The solutions to the equation $x^{2}+1 = 0$ cannot be found on the real number line. Therefore we were required to define these imaginary numbers. But the choice of representing the complex numbers by the y-axis(as to form a plane), I believe is not completely rigorous. I would like you to shed some light on this matter. Also, where is the complex axis located with respect to the 3-dimensional origin. Is it in the 4th dimension?

Comment: It's called the _imaginary_ axis. Complex numbers are called that because they are formed by complexing a real number with an imaginary number. The entire _plane_ is complex. The vertical axis is imaginary (although it's not non-complex).

Comment: There is nothing stopping us from visualizing a point with coordinates $(x,y)$ when we think about the complex number $x + i y$.  We can visualize whatever we want.  And in fact, when we think about complex numbers this way, it turns out that addition and multiplication have very nice visual interpretations.  For example, to multiply two complex numbers, you "add the angles and multiply the lengths".

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by 'not completely rigorous'? It's just a graphical representation of a vector space, in the same way R2 is. There's no actual math being done here.

With regard to the final part of your question, complex numbers come in the form a+bi. There is no imaginary part of a three dimensional vector of reals and no single imaginary part of three dimensional vector of complex numbers.

Comment: A small historical note: this graphical representation of complex numbers came rather late : it is Gauss that has "imposed" it (around 1800) two hundred years after complex numbers were "discovered" (around 1600).